# Examples showing how George Boole's notation differs to modern notation.

Tags: boolean-algebra, math-history

I'm writing a project about George Boole, and was wondering if there was any significant examples showing the change in notation.

Any help would be welcome, thank you.

Comment: You can easily find Boole's notation in his [The Mathematical analysis of Logic (1847)](https://books.google.it/books?id=zv4YAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA25); see e.g. page 25.

Comment: See also [George Boole](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#MathAnalLogi1847) and [The Algebra of Logic Tradition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/).

Comment: I am not sure that this is a rich topic. There are essentially three operators, one of which is implied.